# Typeface used by Werner and Schumann (late 19th or early 20th century)

Tags: font-identification

In order to date a German game of Go-Bang, the only thing I seem to have is the typeface of the numbers *1, 2,* and *3* and the lowercase *a* on the box.

[image]

Note the peculiar digit *1* and the letter *a* which, turning clockwise, ends in a “fish tail”. With a magnifying glass, I had a closer look at the latter and made crude reconstruction of what it looks like (no, not a *G*):

[image]

Here is what I know and found so far:

- I would guess that the style is Jugendstil? Does it have a name?
- *WS&B* stands for Werner and Schumann, a German publisher of games and toys from at least 1879 to 1925.
- I have searched Google an evening and a morning without success. I have searched using all the methods in the requirements list (except for Photoshop which I don’t have) on the peculiar digit *1* without success. They simply don’t come up with anything near this digit *1.*

Could someone please recognize the type and date, period, of use?

Comment: The image you posted looks like it has been printed by letterpress using moveable type - from a bygone era, and stamped in gold foil, or had gold leaf applied. You might find that this is not a font you can find in a digital format - since no one might have created a digital font for it yet.  That's not to say you couldn't perhaps create a font yourself, or modify an existing font - if you have the required skills.  But to expect everything that has ever been printed to be be available as a font to download might be expecting too much.

Comment: Thanks very much Billy Kerr for your comment. Indeed it would not be easy to find it digitized, in fact I can not find this font referenced at all. My question is first of all, what is the name of the font (from around 1900)  It looks like it was rarely used so that might put a date on the box for which it was used.

Comment: Ger, I think what people are getting at is that using a font identification program (or having people here identify a font) is based on typefaces that are actually full typefaces and generally (if not always) refer to typefaces that have been created electronically.  In your situation, I think you would have more luck looking at websites devoted to toy/game collectors--they may be better at helping you identify the letterforms you see on your game.

Answer (score 2):

A digit *1* of that kind was sometimes used with blackletter typefaces to make the digits look more blackletter (normally roman-type digits were used even in blackletter typesetting), here in particular avoiding a “serifed foot”. While this wasn’t very common, there are still numerous typefaces of this kind. At a quick search, I could find the [Yonkers](http://www.1001fonts.com/yonkers-font.html#character-map) and [Westminster Gotisch](http://www.1001fonts.com/westminster-gotisch-font.html#character-map) digitalisations by Dieter Steffmann. As there is otherwise little design variation in digits, I don’t think that you have much hope to narrow it down to a specific typeface. Finally, unless I am very much mistaken, this style of *1* already existed before 1879 and thus won’t help you narrow down the age of your game.

As for the superscript letter, I wouldn’t bet on it being the same typeface as your digits. Moreover, my best bet is that it’s an uppercase *A* from a semi-blackletter typeface, though I cannot exclude an exotic *G.* I have never seen this particular shape (and I have browsed through a lot of blackletter *A*s looking for inspiration for a modern variant), so this might actually be sufficient for identifying the typeface. Unfortunately, I failed to identify this one.

Comment: Advised to look elsewhere I arrived at 
https://typography.guru/forums/topic/1236-what-font-is-used-by-german-game-publisher-wsb/
There the digits 123 were found to resemble (Neue) Schwabacher
http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-41720.html
Indeed they look the same as your Jonkers.

As to the "a" it was found to resemble 
Künstlerschrift (F. Schweimanns for D. Stempel, 1901)
http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-33235.html

Not identical but still very much the same idea.
So that still leaves the actual type to be found.